# How to run a worker on a different thread only if I have one else run the action on the same thread

Tags: c#, .net

I want to run a action on a parallel thread only if there are any free threads.  I do not want to wait till the threads get available (i.e I do not want to queue) instead if no thread is available run the action on the same thread.

So what I did :

```
public static void ExecuetAsyncIfPosible(Action workerAction)
{
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out int worker, out _);

    if (worker > 0)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((status) => workerAction());

    workerAction();
}
```

will this work ?
Or is there a better way ?

Comment: Why do you want this? What is the key difference between these workflows? You can just run a `Task`. By the way, your code isn't working, the number of available threads can change between `GetAvailableThreads` and `QueueUserWorkItem`.

Comment: Are you aware that this kind of functionality is built into the TPL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

Comment: .NET already implements such things through Tasks, the Dataflow classes like `ActionBlock` and Channels. An `ActionBlock<T>` for example  processes any `T` items you post to it. It has its own input buffer and can be configured to use one or more tasks to process multiple itmes

Comment: The requirement `do not want to wait till the threads get available` is rather strange though. A ThreadPool is used to make it *faster* to get a thread. Creating a new thread is expensive. A threadpool can have thousands of threads too and its minimum/maximum size can be configured. If the threadpool is full, it grows by adding threads. That won't be slower than creating a new thread explicitly

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
  int worker = 0;
  int io = 0;
  ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out worker, out io);
```

check if there are more then 0, 
then just:

```
Thread newThread = new Thread (()=>{DoSomething()});
newThread.Start();
```

[you can read Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_ThreadPool_GetAvailableThreads_System_Int32__System_Int32__)